# Plain NiFi Expression language not getting resolved

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use an environment variable which contains the file path, in *NiFi Expression language*. When I just give environment variable `${MY_VAR}` for the file name, it is not getting resolved.

But if there is a space or some other character before the `NiFi EL`, it is being evaluated, but that will make an invalid file name. How to have this resolved without any extra characters.

So as per observation, when the whole content is just an `EL` it is not getting evaluated otherwise, it is.

PS: I am trying give the file name in *Truststore Filename* field in default `StandardSSLContextService`

Comment: As far as I can tell, the truststore and keystore properties on StandardSSLContextService do not support expression language.

Comment: @BryanBende As per the help it says so, but that doesn't justify the case the variables getting resolved when added along with some character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are encountering a bug in Apache NiFi. As Bryan pointed out, the truststore location field is not intended to support the Expression Language. The problem is stemming from an incorrect line at [`StandardSSLContextService:183`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-ssl-context-bundle/nifi-ssl-context-service/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/ssl/StandardSSLContextService.java#L183-L183) where the `.evaluateExpressionAttributes()` method is being invoked in the custom file validator, despite the comment a few lines above explaining the entire reason for this custom validator is because the default supports EL.

I ran a remote debugger and was able to evaluate `${TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION}` using the environment variable `TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION` (which must be set before NiFi is started, because the `VariableRegistry.ENVIRONMENT_SYSTEM_REGISTRY` is only created by `NotificationServiceManager` which is invoked in [`RunNiFi:270`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-bootstrap/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/bootstrap/RunNiFi.java#L270-L270)). I was able to watch it correctly evaluate the environment variable to a file path, but then it was concatenated to the current running directory (`.../nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION`) rather than being treated as an absolute/relative path because the property descriptor is unaware that this is the result of EL evaluation.

I have filed [NIFI-4274](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4274) to document this bug. A workaround is to use a hard-coded truststore location in NiFi and use symlinks on your filesystem to point that at the actual file location if you do not know it at configure time.

Comment: Andy again..:-) Thanks a lot Andy. That explains the problem on detail.

Comment: I just upgraded to 1.4.0, and ${TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME} is still not resolving for me. Is this really fixed?

Comment: I just realized that the "fix" is that it won't resolve environment variables anymore. This is really bad for me, since we don't want users messing with any processors in production. I need to be able to put the truststore location and password in an ENV VAR, since no one is allowed to change anything in production.

Comment: The issue above was not written to support EL in this field, it was to correctly document and *not* evaluate EL in the field. If you want that field to support EL, feel free file a Jira ticket requesting that feature.

Comment: I mean, I understand the rationale. It just seems weird to me. We have to come up with this huge complicated workaround so we can set environment variables, allowing us to build flows in Dev, and then move them to Production. Is there some way that I should be setting my password and truststore_location that I haven't thought of, if I can't use an ENV Variable? Something that won't get overwritten every time we update a flow?